# cors middleware and get error on post api

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nginx, cors

i made a cors middleware and set it for all apis for preventing `cors error` and this is my middleware :

```
$response = $next($request);
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH, PUT');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
return $response;
```

my problem is the headers seems to work just for GET api and and on post api i m getting `cors error`:

it there any config on nginx side or even vue js api call for fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle cors in a right way,
It's better to install `fruitcake/laravel-cors` package, and then put this:

```
\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
```

in `App\Http\Kernel.php` like this:

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

Comment: is there any specific config?

Comment: This package has a config file that creates in `config` directory when you use `publish:vendor` , and in this file, it's enough to set `path` like this:

```
'paths' => ['api/*']
```

Comment: i tested and the headers seem to be same . but just the package works . why?

Comment: I really don't know, I had this problem a few months ago and I've solved it with this package.